# Cannot resolve resource item SvgImage

Tags: c#, winforms, svg, xaf

I am trying to track down a memory leak that I think might be occurring in DevExpress.XtraEditors.SvgImageBox

So I made a class

```
public class MySvgImageBox : SvgImageBox
{
 
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

and changed my code to use this type

```
public class MyGalleryCaptionControl : XtraUserControl
{
 
    internal MySvgImageBox svgImageBoxSelected;
    //etc
```

However resources.GetObject now indicates a problem in the InitializeComponent() code

[image: screen snapshot]

The project builds but at runtime I get the following error

> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 'Could not find any
> resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral
> culture.  Make sure
> "MyAppModule.Win.Features.Jama.Editors.MyGalleryControl.MyGalleryCaptionControl.resources"
> was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "MyApp.Module.Win" at
> compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are
> loadable and fully signed.'

I do see a .resx file for MyGalleryControl

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared when I moved MySvgImageBox.cs to it's own file